# Update columns based on subquery containing "select unnest" clause

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am attempting to update a boolean column in one table based upon the values in a second.

```sql
UPDATE channels
SET contains_photos = TRUE 
WHERE id IN (SELECT unnest(ancestors) 
    FROM channel_tree WHERE id = 11329);
```

The `channel_tree.ancestors` column contains an array of channel IDs. The above is failing with the following error:

> ERROR:  cannot TRUNCATE "channel_tree" because it is being used by active queries in this session

The overriding goal is to set the `contains_photos` column to true for all `ancestors` of a given channel. Any one know how best to alleviate this error, or even an alternative solution?

Comment: Is that the whole code? Isn't there a `truncate` command somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's all of it. There is no `truncate` anywhere in my code.

Comment: Anything unusual in the result of `select * from pg_locks;`?

Comment: Do you have a trigger BEFORE / AFTER UPDATE on table `channels` which could be the source of the failing `TRUNCATE` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why your error says TRUNCATE. It sounds like you have a trigger or rule that is doing a truncate that we can't see.

Here's some alternative ways of doing that same query:

```
UPDATE channels
SET contains_photos = TRUE 
WHERE id = ANY (SELECT ancestors 
    FROM channel_tree WHERE id = 11329);
```

Or with a join:

```
UPDATE channels
SET contains_photos = TRUE
FROM channel_tree
WHERE channels.id = ANY (channel_tree.ancestors)
      AND channel_tree.id = 11329;
```